# Java: How to access members of an object in a class hierarchy where one member changes its data type

Tags: java, inheritance

I have three classes:

```
class A
{
  public Object Person;
}

class B extends A
{
}

class C
{
  public String Name;
}
```

I want to access Name:

```
B b = new B();
C c = new C();
c.Name = "John";

b.Person = c;
String s = b.Person.Name; // This is not allowed. Name is not a property of Person.
```

How can I reference the Name property (for either writing to it or reading from it)?

In fact, I could have a class D, E, F that I need to assign b.Person where each class has completely different properties. So the solution needs to work with class D, E, F, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could considering use some [Generics](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/gentypes.html):

```
class A<T>
{
  public T person;
}

class B extends A<Person>
{
}
```

Or/And use some interfaces.

Anyway its a weird construction, you better just use a Person class where you can set the name. And in a object oriented way use some [polymorphism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_%28computer_science%29).

I saw that you started a variable name with a capital letter, so a small tip: Use [camel-casing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CamelCase) (I fixed it in my example)

Answer (score 3):

You need to cast:

```
String s = ((C)b.Person).Name;
```

Note this is a dangerous method of coding, since now changes to the datatype of `Person` in A could cause this code to throw an exception at runtime. You'd be much better off strongly-typing (i.e. using specific classes rather than `Object`) for your model.

Answer (score 2):

You need to design a better object model.
Using type 'Object' is too abstract, as already pointed out. At some point your code has to deal with a 'concrete' type.
Java is a strongly typed programming language. Some other languages are more fluid and allow this kind of dynamic runtime typing.

Answer (score 0):

You should cast person to `C` if you want to access `C`'s members (since `Person` is of the type `Object`):

```
String s = ((C)b.Person).Name;
```

Two notes:

1. It is not recommended to declare members as public, but as private and declare getter / setter methods to access them.
2. Usually member names start with lower case, not upper.

Answer (score 0):

You can cast b to access the Name property;

```
String s = ((C)b.Person).Name
```

Comment: I was kind of hoping to avoid that. If you have that object all over your code, you'd be constantly casting it.

Comment: Having to cast a lot usually means there is something wrong with your coding. I suggest you define your classes better so you can use something other than `Object`

Answer (score 0):

If your classes are [beans](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaBean) you can use [Commons BeanUtils](http://commons.apache.org/beanutils/api/org/apache/commons/beanutils/BeanUtils.html#getNestedProperty%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.String%29) to read the nested property:

```
BeanUtils.getNestedProperty(b, "person.name");
```

PS: Please try to use Java coding conventions: member names start with lowercase, properties are usualy private and exposed by get/set methods and [so on](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconvtoc-136057.html).